# How to keep icon in changed state once clicked. using css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have bootstrap nav, which uses icons instead of text as a list items.

```css
.third ul li a svg g path g[aria-selected="true"]{
  fill: red;  
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav mb-3 justify-content-around" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="web-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#web" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home"
          aria-selected="true" style="text-align: center;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px"
            width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 172 172" style=" fill:#000000;">
            <g fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt"
              stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0"
              font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal">
              <path d="M0,172v-172h172v172z" fill="none"></path>
              <g fill="#ffffff">   //this one need to be changed on clicked.
                <path
                  d="M23.65,23.65c-4.72427,0 -8.6,3.87573 -8.6,8.6v116.1h2.15h139.75v-116.1c0,-4.72427 -3.87573,-8.6 -8.6,-8.6zM23.65,27.95h124.7c2.40083,0 4.3,1.89917 4.3,4.3v15.05v96.75h-133.3v-96.75v-15.05c0,-2.40083 1.89917,-4.3 4.3,-4.3zM19.35,47.3c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15zM152.65,47.3c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15zM27.95,32.25c-2.37482,0 -4.3,1.92518 -4.3,4.3c0,2.37482 1.92518,4.3 4.3,4.3c2.37482,0 4.3,-1.92518 4.3,-4.3c0,-2.37482 -1.92518,-4.3 -4.3,-4.3zM40.85,32.25c-2.37482,0 -4.3,1.92518 -4.3,4.3c0,2.37482 1.92518,4.3 4.3,4.3c2.37482,0 4.3,-1.92518 4.3,-4.3c0,-2.37482 -1.92518,-4.3 -4.3,-4.3zM53.75,32.25c-2.37482,0 -4.3,1.92518 -4.3,4.3c0,2.37482 1.92518,4.3 4.3,4.3c2.37482,0 4.3,-1.92518 4.3,-4.3c0,-2.37482 -1.92518,-4.3 -4.3,-4.3zM30.1,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM38.7,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM47.3,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM55.9,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM64.5,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM73.1,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM81.7,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM90.3,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM98.9,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM107.5,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM116.1,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM124.7,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM133.3,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM141.9,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM36.55,60.2c-3.53669,0 -6.45,2.91331 -6.45,6.45v60.2c0,3.53669 2.91331,6.45 6.45,6.45h2.15c0.77537,0.01097 1.49657,-0.39641 1.88746,-1.06613c0.39088,-0.66972 0.39088,-1.49803 0,-2.16775c-0.39088,-0.66972 -1.11209,-1.07709 -1.88746,-1.06613h-2.15c-1.21481,0 -2.15,-0.93519 -2.15,-2.15v-60.2c0,-1.21481 0.93519,-2.15 2.15,-2.15h38.7c1.21481,0 2.15,0.93519 2.15,2.15v60.2c0,1.21481 -0.93519,2.15 -2.15,2.15h-2.15c-0.77537,-0.01097 -1.49657,0.39641 -1.88746,1.06613c-0.39088,0.66972 -0.39088,1.49803 0,2.16775c0.39088,0.66972 1.11209,1.07709 1.88746,1.06613h2.15c3.53669,0 6.45,-2.91331 6.45,-6.45v-60.2c0,-3.53669 -2.91331,-6.45 -6.45,-6.45zM96.75,60.2c-3.53669,0 -6.45,2.91331 -6.45,6.45v6.45c0,3.53669 2.91331,6.45 6.45,6.45h38.7c3.53669,0 6.45,-2.91331 6.45,-6.45v-6.45c0,-3.53669 -2.91331,-6.45 -6.45,-6.45zM96.75,64.5h38.7c1.21481,0 2.15,0.93519 2.15,2.15v6.45c0,1.21481 -0.93519,2.15 -2.15,2.15h-38.7c-1.21481,0 -2.15,-0.93519 -2.15,-2.15v-6.45c0,-1.21481 0.93519,-2.15 2.15,-2.15zM90.3,90.3v4.3h51.6v-4.3zM90.3,103.2v4.3h51.6v-4.3zM90.3,116.1v4.3h51.6v-4.3zM47.3,129c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM55.9,129c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM64.5,129c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM90.3,129v4.3h30.1v-4.3z">
                </path>
              </g>
            </g>
          </svg>
          <p>WEB DEVELOPMENT</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <a class="nav-link" id="graphics-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#graphics" role="tab"
          aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false" style="text-align: center;"><svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 172 172"
            style=" fill:#000000;">
            <g fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt"
              stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0"
              font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal">
              <path d="M0,172v-172h172v172z" fill="none"></path>
              <g fill="#ffffff">
                <path
                  d="M13.76,27.52v116.96h82.56c3.29219,0 3.44,-3.44 3.44,-3.44c0,-5.68406 4.63594,-10.32 10.32,-10.32c-5.68406,0 -10.32,-4.63594 -10.32,-10.32c0,-5.68406 4.63594,-10.32 10.32,-10.32h26.51219c1.34375,-1.34375 1.34375,-3.52062 0,-4.86437l-17.2,-18.20781c-1.34375,-1.34375 -3.52062,-1.34375 -4.86437,0l-14.66031,14.66031v-0.01344l-12.85969,12.87313c-0.67188,0.65844 -1.55875,0.99437 -2.44563,0.99437c-0.87344,0 -1.76031,-0.33594 -2.43219,-0.99437c-1.34375,-1.35719 -1.34375,-3.52063 0,-4.87781l13.07469,-13.06125l-30.75844,-33.55344c-0.61812,-0.67188 -1.46469,-1.075 -2.37844,-1.11531c-0.9675,-0.04031 -1.81406,0.29563 -2.48594,0.91375l-38.94188,35.97219v-64.40594h130.72v58.48c-0.01344,1.23625 0.63156,2.39188 1.70656,3.02344c1.075,0.61813 2.39187,0.61813 3.46687,0c1.075,-0.63156 1.72,-1.78719 1.70656,-3.02344v-65.36zM120.4,51.6c-5.6975,0 -10.32,4.6225 -10.32,10.32c0,5.6975 4.6225,10.32 10.32,10.32c5.6975,0 10.32,-4.6225 10.32,-10.32c0,-5.6975 -4.6225,-10.32 -10.32,-10.32zM151.36,113.52c-2.45906,0 -4.71656,1.31688 -5.95281,3.44h-35.32719c-1.23625,-0.01344 -2.39187,0.63156 -3.02344,1.70656c-0.61813,1.075 -0.61813,2.39187 0,3.46687c0.63156,1.075 1.78719,1.72 3.02344,1.70656h35.32719c1.22281,2.12313 3.49375,3.44 5.95281,3.44c2.45906,0 4.71656,-1.31687 5.95281,-3.44h11.24719c1.23625,0.01344 2.39188,-0.63156 3.02344,-1.70656c0.61813,-1.075 0.61813,-2.39187 0,-3.46687c-0.63156,-1.075 -1.78719,-1.72 -3.02344,-1.70656h-11.24719c-1.22281,-2.12312 -3.49375,-3.44 -5.95281,-3.44zM130.72,134.16c-2.45906,0 -4.71656,1.31688 -5.95281,3.44h-14.68719c-1.23625,-0.01344 -2.39187,0.63156 -3.02344,1.70656c-0.61813,1.075 -0.61813,2.39187 0,3.46687c0.63156,1.075 1.78719,1.72 3.02344,1.70656h14.68719c1.22281,2.12313 3.49375,3.44 5.95281,3.44c2.45906,0 4.71656,-1.31687 5.95281,-3.44h31.88719c1.23625,0.01344 2.39188,-0.63156 3.02344,-1.70656c0.61813,-1.075 0.61813,-2.39187 0,-3.46687c-0.63156,-1.075 -1.78719,-1.72 -3.02344,-1.70656h-31.88719c-1.22281,-2.12312 -3.49375,-3.44 -5.95281,-3.44zM151.36,154.8c-2.45906,0 -4.71656,1.31688 -5.95281,3.44h-35.32719c-1.23625,-0.01344 -2.39187,0.63156 -3.02344,1.70656c-0.61813,1.075 -0.61813,2.39187 0,3.46687c0.63156,1.075 1.78719,1.72 3.02344,1.70656h35.32719c1.22281,2.12313 3.49375,3.44 5.95281,3.44c2.45906,0 4.71656,-1.31687 5.95281,-3.44h11.24719c1.23625,0.01344 2.39188,-0.63156 3.02344,-1.70656c0.61813,-1.075 0.61813,-2.39187 0,-3.46687c-0.63156,-1.075 -1.78719,-1.72 -3.02344,-1.70656h-11.24719c-1.22281,-2.12312 -3.49375,-3.44 -5.95281,-3.44z">
                </path>
              </g>
            </g>
          </svg>
          <p>GRAPHICS DESIGN</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <a class="nav-link" id="app-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#app" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact"
          aria-selected="false" style="text-align: center;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px"
            width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 172 172" style=" fill:#000000;">
            <g fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt"
              stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0"
              font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal">
              <path d="M0,172v-172h172v172z" fill="none"></path>
              <g fill="#ffffff">
                <path
                  d="M51.6,10.32c-5.68406,0 -10.32,4.63594 -10.32,10.32v130.72c0,5.68406 4.63594,10.32 10.32,10.32h68.8c5.68406,0 10.32,-4.63594 10.32,-10.32v-130.72c0,-5.68406 -4.63594,-10.32 -10.32,-10.32zM48.16,34.4h75.68v99.76h-75.68zM77.0775,54.9325c-0.08062,0.02688 -0.14781,0.06719 -0.215,0.1075c-0.48375,0.16125 -0.87344,0.52406 -1.06156,1.00781c-0.18812,0.48375 -0.16125,1.02125 0.09406,1.46469l1.8275,3.7625c-3.3325,2.48594 -5.4825,6.39625 -5.4825,10.965h27.52c0,-4.56875 -2.15,-8.47906 -5.4825,-10.965l1.8275,-3.7625c0.3225,-0.60469 0.25531,-1.33031 -0.16125,-1.86781c-0.41656,-0.52406 -1.11531,-0.76594 -1.77375,-0.60469c-0.48375,0.14781 -0.87344,0.49719 -1.075,0.9675l-1.72,3.5475c-1.65281,-0.68531 -3.44,-1.075 -5.375,-1.075c-1.935,0 -3.72219,0.38969 -5.375,1.075l-1.72,-3.5475c-0.26875,-0.65844 -0.90031,-1.08844 -1.6125,-1.075c-0.06719,0 -0.14781,0 -0.215,0zM65.0375,68.6925c-0.14781,0.02688 -0.29562,0.06719 -0.43,0.1075c-1.59906,0.36281 -2.72781,1.80063 -2.6875,3.44v17.2c-0.01344,1.23625 0.63156,2.39188 1.70656,3.02344c1.075,0.61813 2.39187,0.61813 3.46687,0c1.075,-0.63156 1.72,-1.78719 1.70656,-3.02344v-17.2c0.04031,-0.99437 -0.36281,-1.94844 -1.075,-2.62031c-0.72562,-0.68531 -1.70656,-1.02125 -2.6875,-0.92719zM106.3175,68.6925c-0.14781,0.02688 -0.29562,0.06719 -0.43,0.1075c-1.59906,0.36281 -2.72781,1.80063 -2.6875,3.44v17.2c-0.01344,1.23625 0.63156,2.39188 1.70656,3.02344c1.075,0.61813 2.39187,0.61813 3.46687,0c1.075,-0.63156 1.72,-1.78719 1.70656,-3.02344v-17.2c0.04031,-0.99437 -0.36281,-1.94844 -1.075,-2.62031c-0.72562,-0.68531 -1.70656,-1.02125 -2.6875,-0.92719zM72.24,75.68v17.2c0,2.71438 1.33031,4.89125 3.44,6.02v7.74c-0.01344,1.23625 0.63156,2.39188 1.70656,3.02344c1.075,0.61813 2.39187,0.61813 3.46687,0c1.075,-0.63156 1.72,-1.78719 1.70656,-3.02344v-6.88h6.88v6.88c-0.01344,1.23625 0.63156,2.39188 1.70656,3.02344c1.075,0.61813 2.39187,0.61813 3.46687,0c1.075,-0.63156 1.72,-1.78719 1.70656,-3.02344v-7.74c2.10969,-1.12875 3.44,-3.30562 3.44,-6.02v-17.2zM75.68,144.48h20.64c1.90813,0 3.44,1.53188 3.44,3.44c0,1.90813 -1.53187,3.44 -3.44,3.44h-20.64c-1.89469,0 -3.44,-1.53187 -3.44,-3.44c0,-1.90812 1.54531,-3.44 3.44,-3.44z">
                </path>
              </g>
            </g>
          </svg>
          <p>APP DEVELOPMENT</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <a class="nav-link" id="branding-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#branding" role="tab"
          aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false" style="text-align: center;"><svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 172 172"
            style=" fill:#000000;">
            <g fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt"
              stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0"
              font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal">
              <path d="M0,172v-172h172v172z" fill="none"></path>
              <g fill="#ffffff">
                <path
                  d="M39.88418,23.65c-3.84115,0 -6.87548,3.43447 -6.39961,7.24785l13.50469,108.0333c0.66979,5.36369 5.2621,9.41885 10.66601,9.41885h49.31982c5.4032,0 9.99371,-4.05229 10.66602,-9.41465l0.09238,-0.72647v-0.0042c0.06243,-0.21543 0.09076,-0.43929 0.08398,-0.66348l2.6875,-21.44121h11.01035c7.37917,0 13.69459,-5.38673 14.86103,-12.67324l4.47217,-27.95c1.45591,-9.10503 -5.64731,-17.42676 -14.86523,-17.42676h-8.23467l3.39297,-27.15215c0.47587,-3.81329 -2.55735,-7.24785 -6.39961,-7.24785zM39.88418,27.95h84.85781c1.33065,0 2.29803,1.09793 2.1332,2.41875l-0.23516,1.88125h-18.52695c-0.77537,-0.01097 -1.49657,0.39641 -1.88746,1.06613c-0.39088,0.66972 -0.39088,1.49803 0,2.16775c0.39088,0.66972 1.11209,1.07709 1.88746,1.06613h17.98945l-2.92266,23.38125c0,0.0014 0,0.0028 0,0.0042l-1.33535,10.75l-2.90166,23.17549l-1.11699,8.96113c-0.00801,0.0376 -0.01501,0.0754 -0.02099,0.11338l-1.22197,9.83037l-0.11338,0.91543v0.0042l-2.72529,21.76455h-17.45615c-0.77537,-0.01097 -1.49657,0.39641 -1.88746,1.06613c-0.39088,0.66972 -0.39088,1.49803 0,2.16775c0.39088,0.66972 1.11209,1.07709 1.88746,1.06613h16.75908c-0.89022,2.53844 -3.27611,4.3 -6.07207,4.3h-49.31982c-3.20067,0 -5.86645,-2.30891 -6.35762,-5.45059l0.28975,-1.6083l-0.58789,-0.62568l-12.61025,-100.90722l0.29814,-1.66709l-0.58789,-0.62988l-0.34853,-2.79668c-0.16207,-1.31881 0.80726,-2.41455 2.1332,-2.41455zM45.22559,32.25l-1.72168,0.86504l-0.34014,1.89385l1.31436,1.40674l0.74746,0.13437l1.72168,-0.86504l0.34014,-1.89385l-1.31436,-1.40674zM53.82559,32.25l-1.72168,0.86504l-0.34014,1.89385l1.31436,1.40674l0.74746,0.13437l1.72168,-0.86504l0.34014,-1.89385l-1.31436,-1.40674zM62.42559,32.25l-1.72168,0.86504l-0.34014,1.89385l1.31436,1.40674l0.74746,0.13437l1.72168,-0.86504l0.34014,-1.89385l-1.31436,-1.40674zM71.02559,32.25l-1.72168,0.86504l-0.34014,1.89385l1.31436,1.40674l0.74746,0.13437l1.72168,-0.86504l0.34014,-1.89385l-1.31436,-1.40674zM79.62559,32.25l-1.72168,0.86504l-0.34014,1.89385l1.31436,1.40674l0.74746,0.13437l1.72168,-0.86504l0.34014,-1.89385l-1.31436,-1.40674zM88.22559,32.25l-1.72168,0.86504l-0.34014,1.89385l1.31436,1.40674l0.74746,0.13437l1.72168,-0.86504l0.34014,-1.89385l-1.31436,-1.40674zM71.56309,49.45c-0.77537,-0.01097 -1.49657,0.39641 -1.88746,1.06613c-0.39088,0.66972 -0.39088,1.49803 0,2.16775c0.39088,0.66972 1.11209,1.07709 1.88746,1.06613c2.50833,0 4.56293,1.20464 6.13506,3.2082c1.20324,1.53344 2.03821,3.53234 2.36836,5.61436c-5.86163,1.05077 -10.39395,6.08201 -10.62822,12.19033c-0.1498,0.64408 0.00508,1.32126 0.41997,1.83618c0.41489,0.51492 1.04363,0.8103 1.70483,0.80093c0.60814,0.00823 1.19131,-0.24146 1.60507,-0.68723c0.41375,-0.44576 0.61938,-1.0459 0.56593,-1.65174c0.10992,-4.96231 4.30981,-8.85682 9.43145,-8.36904c4.42078,0.42168 7.74756,4.45424 7.74756,9.01992v2.76309c0,6.15795 2.25101,11.81655 5.97969,16.1502c5.61842,6.53075 5.18303,16.24827 -1.56211,21.38662c-3.61541,2.75506 -8.11486,4.38818 -13.01758,4.38818c-4.90272,0 -9.40217,-1.63312 -13.01758,-4.38818c-3.42177,-2.60567 -5.17457,-6.34141 -5.3918,-10.30068c0.05093,-0.60445 -0.15582,-1.2023 -0.56928,-1.64615c-0.41346,-0.44385 -0.99517,-0.69242 -1.60171,-0.68441c-0.66859,-0.00776 -1.30274,0.29595 -1.71581,0.82174c-0.41306,0.52579 -0.55802,1.21381 -0.3922,1.86156c0.31298,5.06906 2.65555,10.01078 7.06728,13.37031c4.33529,3.30364 9.76091,5.26582 15.62109,5.26582c5.86018,0 11.2858,-1.96218 15.62109,-5.26582c8.76066,-6.67375 9.31377,-19.37001 2.22139,-27.61406c-3.08252,-3.58265 -4.94248,-8.23277 -4.94248,-13.34512v-2.76309c0,-4.67378 -2.40882,-9.01 -6.17705,-11.40928c4.34417,-0.40201 7.64269,-1.42991 10.09912,-3.14941c3.25492,-2.27844 4.67793,-5.85044 4.67793,-9.55322v-2.15h-2.15c-4.47917,0 -9.04881,0.50786 -12.78662,2.37676c-2.51139,1.25569 -4.58672,3.32503 -5.69414,6.05947c-0.54613,-1.28497 -1.24655,-2.49477 -2.09961,-3.58193c-2.2237,-2.83393 -5.57796,-4.8543 -9.51963,-4.8543zM99.08897,53.94736c-0.37408,1.44804 -1.01596,2.70202 -2.42295,3.68691c-1.73524,1.21467 -5.02668,1.99762 -9.43145,2.30117c0.5921,-1.87512 1.63738,-3.29833 3.56514,-4.26221c2.12634,-1.06317 5.13408,-1.52573 8.28926,-1.72588zM127.21113,62.35h8.77217c6.65338,0 11.67082,5.87792 10.61982,12.45068l-4.47217,27.9458c-0.83736,5.23079 -5.31839,9.05352 -10.61563,9.05352h-10.47285l0.80205,-6.45h8.30186c3.21571,0 5.97181,-2.40771 6.39541,-5.59756l3.15361,-23.65c0.51087,-3.82834 -2.52814,-7.30244 -6.39121,-7.30244h-6.89092zM125.87998,73.1h7.42422c1.33993,0 2.30613,1.10399 2.12901,2.43135l-3.15361,23.65c0,0.0014 0,0.0028 0,0.0042c-0.144,1.08425 -1.04031,1.86445 -2.1332,1.86445h-7.76436l0.82725,-6.65576zM71.02978,81.22129l-1.72168,0.86504l-0.34014,1.89385l1.31855,1.41094l0.74326,0.13018l1.72588,-0.86084l0.33594,-1.89805l-1.31436,-1.40674zM67.87197,88.7001l-1.72168,0.86084l-0.34014,1.89805l1.31855,1.40674l0.74326,0.13437l1.72168,-0.86504l0.34014,-1.89805l-1.31436,-1.40674zM63.33262,95.44404l-1.72168,0.86504l-0.34014,1.89385l1.31855,1.41094l0.74326,0.13018l1.72588,-0.86084l0.33594,-1.89805l-1.31436,-1.40674zM58.12559,135.45l-1.72168,0.86504l-0.34014,1.89385l1.31436,1.40674l0.74746,0.13438l1.72168,-0.86504l0.34014,-1.89385l-1.31436,-1.40674zM66.72559,135.45l-1.72168,0.86504l-0.34014,1.89385l1.31436,1.40674l0.74746,0.13438l1.72168,-0.86504l0.34014,-1.89385l-1.31436,-1.40674zM75.32559,135.45l-1.72168,0.86504l-0.34014,1.89385l1.31436,1.40674l0.74746,0.13438l1.72168,-0.86504l0.34014,-1.89385l-1.31436,-1.40674zM83.92559,135.45l-1.72168,0.86504l-0.34014,1.89385l1.31436,1.40674l0.74746,0.13438l1.72168,-0.86504l0.34014,-1.89385l-1.31436,-1.40674z">
                </path>
              </g>
            </g>
          </svg>
          <br>
          <p>BRANDING</p>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

The icon I used here is embedded SVG from icons8.com. Initially the fill property for `<g fill=#fff;>` is white but I wanted to make it red on click.
I used CSS property,

```
.third ul li a svg g path g[aria-selected="true"]{
  fill: red;
  
}
```

third is the class name inside which this nav is defined. I even tried using `:active` but that only changes color once clicked. I also used aria-selected true property but doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: Remove the default fill property from svg and apply by CSS.  add css for active `.nav-link:active svg { fill: red  }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add css on `a` acitve to change svg color

```css
ul li a:hover g,
ul li a.active g{
  fill: red;  
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav mb-3 justify-content-around" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="web-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#web" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home"
          aria-selected="true" style="text-align: center;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px"
            width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 172 172" style=" fill:#000000;">
            <g fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt"
              stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0"
              font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal">
              <path d="M0,172v-172h172v172z" fill="none"></path>
              <g fill="#ffffff">   //this one need to be changed on clicked.
                <path
                  d="M23.65,23.65c-4.72427,0 -8.6,3.87573 -8.6,8.6v116.1h2.15h139.75v-116.1c0,-4.72427 -3.87573,-8.6 -8.6,-8.6zM23.65,27.95h124.7c2.40083,0 4.3,1.89917 4.3,4.3v15.05v96.75h-133.3v-96.75v-15.05c0,-2.40083 1.89917,-4.3 4.3,-4.3zM19.35,47.3c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15zM152.65,47.3c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15zM27.95,32.25c-2.37482,0 -4.3,1.92518 -4.3,4.3c0,2.37482 1.92518,4.3 4.3,4.3c2.37482,0 4.3,-1.92518 4.3,-4.3c0,-2.37482 -1.92518,-4.3 -4.3,-4.3zM40.85,32.25c-2.37482,0 -4.3,1.92518 -4.3,4.3c0,2.37482 1.92518,4.3 4.3,4.3c2.37482,0 4.3,-1.92518 4.3,-4.3c0,-2.37482 -1.92518,-4.3 -4.3,-4.3zM53.75,32.25c-2.37482,0 -4.3,1.92518 -4.3,4.3c0,2.37482 1.92518,4.3 4.3,4.3c2.37482,0 4.3,-1.92518 4.3,-4.3c0,-2.37482 -1.92518,-4.3 -4.3,-4.3zM30.1,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM38.7,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM47.3,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM55.9,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM64.5,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM73.1,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM81.7,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM90.3,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM98.9,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM107.5,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM116.1,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM124.7,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM133.3,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM141.9,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM36.55,60.2c-3.53669,0 -6.45,2.91331 -6.45,6.45v60.2c0,3.53669 2.91331,6.45 6.45,6.45h2.15c0.77537,0.01097 1.49657,-0.39641 1.88746,-1.06613c0.39088,-0.66972 0.39088,-1.49803 0,-2.16775c-0.39088,-0.66972 -1.11209,-1.07709 -1.88746,-1.06613h-2.15c-1.21481,0 -2.15,-0.93519 -2.15,-2.15v-60.2c0,-1.21481 0.93519,-2.15 2.15,-2.15h38.7c1.21481,0 2.15,0.93519 2.15,2.15v60.2c0,1.21481 -0.93519,2.15 -2.15,2.15h-2.15c-0.77537,-0.01097 -1.49657,0.39641 -1.88746,1.06613c-0.39088,0.66972 -0.39088,1.49803 0,2.16775c0.39088,0.66972 1.11209,1.07709 1.88746,1.06613h2.15c3.53669,0 6.45,-2.91331 6.45,-6.45v-60.2c0,-3.53669 -2.91331,-6.45 -6.45,-6.45zM96.75,60.2c-3.53669,0 -6.45,2.91331 -6.45,6.45v6.45c0,3.53669 2.91331,6.45 6.45,6.45h38.7c3.53669,0 6.45,-2.91331 6.45,-6.45v-6.45c0,-3.53669 -2.91331,-6.45 -6.45,-6.45zM96.75,64.5h38.7c1.21481,0 2.15,0.93519 2.15,2.15v6.45c0,1.21481 -0.93519,2.15 -2.15,2.15h-38.7c-1.21481,0 -2.15,-0.93519 -2.15,-2.15v-6.45c0,-1.21481 0.93519,-2.15 2.15,-2.15zM90.3,90.3v4.3h51.6v-4.3zM90.3,103.2v4.3h51.6v-4.3zM90.3,116.1v4.3h51.6v-4.3zM47.3,129c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM55.9,129c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM64.5,129c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM90.3,129v4.3h30.1v-4.3z">
                </path>
              </g>
            </g>
          </svg>
          <p>WEB DEVELOPMENT</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <a class="nav-link" id="graphics-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#graphics" role="tab"
          aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false" style="text-align: center;"><svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 172 172"
            style=" fill:#000000;">
            <g fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt"
              stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0"
              font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal">
              <path d="M0,172v-172h172v172z" fill="none"></path>
              <g fill="#ffffff">
                <path
                  d="M13.76,27.52v116.96h82.56c3.29219,0 3.44,-3.44 3.44,-3.44c0,-5.68406 4.63594,-10.32 10.32,-10.32c-5.68406,0 -10.32,-4.63594 -10.32,-10.32c0,-5.68406 4.63594,-10.32 10.32,-10.32h26.51219c1.34375,-1.34375 1.34375,-3.52062 0,-4.86437l-17.2,-18.20781c-1.34375,-1.34375 -3.52062,-1.34375 -4.86437,0l-14.66031,14.66031v-0.01344l-12.85969,12.87313c-0.67188,0.65844 -1.55875,0.99437 -2.44563,0.99437c-0.87344,0 -1.76031,-0.33594 -2.43219,-0.99437c-1.34375,-1.35719 -1.34375,-3.52063 0,-4.87781l13.07469,-13.06125l-30.75844,-33.55344c-0.61812,-0.67188 -1.46469,-1.075 -2.37844,-1.11531c-0.9675,-0.04031 -1.81406,0.29563 -2.48594,0.91375l-38.94188,35.97219v-64.40594h130.72v58.48c-0.01344,1.23625 0.63156,2.39188 1.70656,3.02344c1.075,0.61813 2.39187,0.61813 3.46687,0c1.075,-0.63156 1.72,-1.78719 1.70656,-3.02344v-65.36zM120.4,51.6c-5.6975,0 -10.32,4.6225 -10.32,10.32c0,5.6975 4.6225,10.32 10.32,10.32c5.6975,0 10.32,-4.6225 10.32,-10.32c0,-5.6975 -4.6225,-10.32 -10.32,-10.32zM151.36,113.52c-2.45906,0 -4.71656,1.31688 -5.95281,3.44h-35.32719c-1.23625,-0.01344 -2.39187,0.63156 -3.02344,1.70656c-0.61813,1.075 -0.61813,2.39187 0,3.46687c0.63156,1.075 1.78719,1.72 3.02344,1.70656h35.32719c1.22281,2.12313 3.49375,3.44 5.95281,3.44c2.45906,0 4.71656,-1.31687 5.95281,-3.44h11.24719c1.23625,0.01344 2.39188,-0.63156 3.02344,-1.70656c0.61813,-1.075 0.61813,-2.39187 0,-3.46687c-0.63156,-1.075 -1.78719,-1.72 -3.02344,-1.70656h-11.24719c-1.22281,-2.12312 -3.49375,-3.44 -5.95281,-3.44zM130.72,134.16c-2.45906,0 -4.71656,1.31688 -5.95281,3.44h-14.68719c-1.23625,-0.01344 -2.39187,0.63156 -3.02344,1.70656c-0.61813,1.075 -0.61813,2.39187 0,3.46687c0.63156,1.075 1.78719,1.72 3.02344,1.70656h14.68719c1.22281,2.12313 3.49375,3.44 5.95281,3.44c2.45906,0 4.71656,-1.31687 5.95281,-3.44h31.88719c1.23625,0.01344 2.39188,-0.63156 3.02344,-1.70656c0.61813,-1.075 0.61813,-2.39187 0,-3.46687c-0.63156,-1.075 -1.78719,-1.72 -3.02344,-1.70656h-31.88719c-1.22281,-2.12312 -3.49375,-3.44 -5.95281,-3.44zM151.36,154.8c-2.45906,0 -4.71656,1.31688 -5.95281,3.44h-35.32719c-1.23625,-0.01344 -2.39187,0.63156 -3.02344,1.70656c-0.61813,1.075 -0.61813,2.39187 0,3.46687c0.63156,1.075 1.78719,1.72 3.02344,1.70656h35.32719c1.22281,2.12313 3.49375,3.44 5.95281,3.44c2.45906,0 4.71656,-1.31687 5.95281,-3.44h11.24719c1.23625,0.01344 2.39188,-0.63156 3.02344,-1.70656c0.61813,-1.075 0.61813,-2.39187 0,-3.46687c-0.63156,-1.075 -1.78719,-1.72 -3.02344,-1.70656h-11.24719c-1.22281,-2.12312 -3.49375,-3.44 -5.95281,-3.44z">
                </path>
              </g>
            </g>
          </svg>
          <p>GRAPHICS DESIGN</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <a class="nav-link" id="app-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#app" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact"
          aria-selected="false" style="text-align: center;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px"
            width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 172 172" style=" fill:#000000;">
            <g fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt"
              stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0"
              font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal">
              <path d="M0,172v-172h172v172z" fill="none"></path>
              <g fill="#ffffff">
                <path
                  d="M51.6,10.32c-5.68406,0 -10.32,4.63594 -10.32,10.32v130.72c0,5.68406 4.63594,10.32 10.32,10.32h68.8c5.68406,0 10.32,-4.63594 10.32,-10.32v-130.72c0,-5.68406 -4.63594,-10.32 -10.32,-10.32zM48.16,34.4h75.68v99.76h-75.68zM77.0775,54.9325c-0.08062,0.02688 -0.14781,0.06719 -0.215,0.1075c-0.48375,0.16125 -0.87344,0.52406 -1.06156,1.00781c-0.18812,0.48375 -0.16125,1.02125 0.09406,1.46469l1.8275,3.7625c-3.3325,2.48594 -5.4825,6.39625 -5.4825,10.965h27.52c0,-4.56875 -2.15,-8.47906 -5.4825,-10.965l1.8275,-3.7625c0.3225,-0.60469 0.25531,-1.33031 -0.16125,-1.86781c-0.41656,-0.52406 -1.11531,-0.76594 -1.77375,-0.60469c-0.48375,0.14781 -0.87344,0.49719 -1.075,0.9675l-1.72,3.5475c-1.65281,-0.68531 -3.44,-1.075 -5.375,-1.075c-1.935,0 -3.72219,0.38969 -5.375,1.075l-1.72,-3.5475c-0.26875,-0.65844 -0.90031,-1.08844 -1.6125,-1.075c-0.06719,0 -0.14781,0 -0.215,0zM65.0375,68.6925c-0.14781,0.02688 -0.29562,0.06719 -0.43,0.1075c-1.59906,0.36281 -2.72781,1.80063 -2.6875,3.44v17.2c-0.01344,1.23625 0.63156,2.39188 1.70656,3.02344c1.075,0.61813 2.39187,0.61813 3.46687,0c1.075,-0.63156 1.72,-1.78719 1.70656,-3.02344v-17.2c0.04031,-0.99437 -0.36281,-1.94844 -1.075,-2.62031c-0.72562,-0.68531 -1.70656,-1.02125 -2.6875,-0.92719zM106.3175,68.6925c-0.14781,0.02688 -0.29562,0.06719 -0.43,0.1075c-1.59906,0.36281 -2.72781,1.80063 -2.6875,3.44v17.2c-0.01344,1.23625 0.63156,2.39188 1.70656,3.02344c1.075,0.61813 2.39187,0.61813 3.46687,0c1.075,-0.63156 1.72,-1.78719 1.70656,-3.02344v-17.2c0.04031,-0.99437 -0.36281,-1.94844 -1.075,-2.62031c-0.72562,-0.68531 -1.70656,-1.02125 -2.6875,-0.92719zM72.24,75.68v17.2c0,2.71438 1.33031,4.89125 3.44,6.02v7.74c-0.01344,1.23625 0.63156,2.39188 1.70656,3.02344c1.075,0.61813 2.39187,0.61813 3.46687,0c1.075,-0.63156 1.72,-1.78719 1.70656,-3.02344v-6.88h6.88v6.88c-0.01344,1.23625 0.63156,2.39188 1.70656,3.02344c1.075,0.61813 2.39187,0.61813 3.46687,0c1.075,-0.63156 1.72,-1.78719 1.70656,-3.02344v-7.74c2.10969,-1.12875 3.44,-3.30562 3.44,-6.02v-17.2zM75.68,144.48h20.64c1.90813,0 3.44,1.53188 3.44,3.44c0,1.90813 -1.53187,3.44 -3.44,3.44h-20.64c-1.89469,0 -3.44,-1.53187 -3.44,-3.44c0,-1.90812 1.54531,-3.44 3.44,-3.44z">
                </path>
              </g>
            </g>
          </svg>
          <p>APP DEVELOPMENT</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <a class="nav-link" id="branding-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#branding" role="tab"
          aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false" style="text-align: center;"><svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 172 172"
            style=" fill:#000000;">
            <g fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt"
              stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0"
              font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal">
              <path d="M0,172v-172h172v172z" fill="none"></path>
              <g fill="#ffffff">
                <path
                  d="M39.88418,23.65c-3.84115,0 -6.87548,3.43447 -6.39961,7.24785l13.50469,108.0333c0.66979,5.36369 5.2621,9.41885 10.66601,9.41885h49.31982c5.4032,0 9.99371,-4.05229 10.66602,-9.41465l0.09238,-0.72647v-0.0042c0.06243,-0.21543 0.09076,-0.43929 0.08398,-0.66348l2.6875,-21.44121h11.01035c7.37917,0 13.69459,-5.38673 14.86103,-12.67324l4.47217,-27.95c1.45591,-9.10503 -5.64731,-17.42676 -14.86523,-17.42676h-8.23467l3.39297,-27.15215c0.47587,-3.81329 -2.55735,-7.24785 -6.39961,-7.24785zM39.88418,27.95h84.85781c1.33065,0 2.29803,1.09793 2.1332,2.41875l-0.23516,1.88125h-18.52695c-0.77537,-0.01097 -1.49657,0.39641 -1.88746,1.06613c-0.39088,0.66972 -0.39088,1.49803 0,2.16775c0.39088,0.66972 1.11209,1.07709 1.88746,1.06613h17.98945l-2.92266,23.38125c0,0.0014 0,0.0028 0,0.0042l-1.33535,10.75l-2.90166,23.17549l-1.11699,8.96113c-0.00801,0.0376 -0.01501,0.0754 -0.02099,0.11338l-1.22197,9.83037l-0.11338,0.91543v0.0042l-2.72529,21.76455h-17.45615c-0.77537,-0.01097 -1.49657,0.39641 -1.88746,1.06613c-0.39088,0.66972 -0.39088,1.49803 0,2.16775c0.39088,0.66972 1.11209,1.07709 1.88746,1.06613h16.75908c-0.89022,2.53844 -3.27611,4.3 -6.07207,4.3h-49.31982c-3.20067,0 -5.86645,-2.30891 -6.35762,-5.45059l0.28975,-1.6083l-0.58789,-0.62568l-12.61025,-100.90722l0.29814,-1.66709l-0.58789,-0.62988l-0.34853,-2.79668c-0.16207,-1.31881 0.80726,-2.41455 2.1332,-2.41455zM45.22559,32.25l-1.72168,0.86504l-0.34014,1.89385l1.31436,1.40674l0.74746,0.13437l1.72168,-0.86504l0.34014,-1.89385l-1.31436,-1.40674zM53.82559,32.25l-1.72168,0.86504l-0.34014,1.89385l1.31436,1.40674l0.74746,0.13437l1.72168,-0.86504l0.34014,-1.89385l-1.31436,-1.40674zM62.42559,32.25l-1.72168,0.86504l-0.34014,1.89385l1.31436,1.40674l0.74746,0.13437l1.72168,-0.86504l0.34014,-1.89385l-1.31436,-1.40674zM71.02559,32.25l-1.72168,0.86504l-0.34014,1.89385l1.31436,1.40674l0.74746,0.13437l1.72168,-0.86504l0.34014,-1.89385l-1.31436,-1.40674zM79.62559,32.25l-1.72168,0.86504l-0.34014,1.89385l1.31436,1.40674l0.74746,0.13437l1.72168,-0.86504l0.34014,-1.89385l-1.31436,-1.40674zM88.22559,32.25l-1.72168,0.86504l-0.34014,1.89385l1.31436,1.40674l0.74746,0.13437l1.72168,-0.86504l0.34014,-1.89385l-1.31436,-1.40674zM71.56309,49.45c-0.77537,-0.01097 -1.49657,0.39641 -1.88746,1.06613c-0.39088,0.66972 -0.39088,1.49803 0,2.16775c0.39088,0.66972 1.11209,1.07709 1.88746,1.06613c2.50833,0 4.56293,1.20464 6.13506,3.2082c1.20324,1.53344 2.03821,3.53234 2.36836,5.61436c-5.86163,1.05077 -10.39395,6.08201 -10.62822,12.19033c-0.1498,0.64408 0.00508,1.32126 0.41997,1.83618c0.41489,0.51492 1.04363,0.8103 1.70483,0.80093c0.60814,0.00823 1.19131,-0.24146 1.60507,-0.68723c0.41375,-0.44576 0.61938,-1.0459 0.56593,-1.65174c0.10992,-4.96231 4.30981,-8.85682 9.43145,-8.36904c4.42078,0.42168 7.74756,4.45424 7.74756,9.01992v2.76309c0,6.15795 2.25101,11.81655 5.97969,16.1502c5.61842,6.53075 5.18303,16.24827 -1.56211,21.38662c-3.61541,2.75506 -8.11486,4.38818 -13.01758,4.38818c-4.90272,0 -9.40217,-1.63312 -13.01758,-4.38818c-3.42177,-2.60567 -5.17457,-6.34141 -5.3918,-10.30068c0.05093,-0.60445 -0.15582,-1.2023 -0.56928,-1.64615c-0.41346,-0.44385 -0.99517,-0.69242 -1.60171,-0.68441c-0.66859,-0.00776 -1.30274,0.29595 -1.71581,0.82174c-0.41306,0.52579 -0.55802,1.21381 -0.3922,1.86156c0.31298,5.06906 2.65555,10.01078 7.06728,13.37031c4.33529,3.30364 9.76091,5.26582 15.62109,5.26582c5.86018,0 11.2858,-1.96218 15.62109,-5.26582c8.76066,-6.67375 9.31377,-19.37001 2.22139,-27.61406c-3.08252,-3.58265 -4.94248,-8.23277 -4.94248,-13.34512v-2.76309c0,-4.67378 -2.40882,-9.01 -6.17705,-11.40928c4.34417,-0.40201 7.64269,-1.42991 10.09912,-3.14941c3.25492,-2.27844 4.67793,-5.85044 4.67793,-9.55322v-2.15h-2.15c-4.47917,0 -9.04881,0.50786 -12.78662,2.37676c-2.51139,1.25569 -4.58672,3.32503 -5.69414,6.05947c-0.54613,-1.28497 -1.24655,-2.49477 -2.09961,-3.58193c-2.2237,-2.83393 -5.57796,-4.8543 -9.51963,-4.8543zM99.08897,53.94736c-0.37408,1.44804 -1.01596,2.70202 -2.42295,3.68691c-1.73524,1.21467 -5.02668,1.99762 -9.43145,2.30117c0.5921,-1.87512 1.63738,-3.29833 3.56514,-4.26221c2.12634,-1.06317 5.13408,-1.52573 8.28926,-1.72588zM127.21113,62.35h8.77217c6.65338,0 11.67082,5.87792 10.61982,12.45068l-4.47217,27.9458c-0.83736,5.23079 -5.31839,9.05352 -10.61563,9.05352h-10.47285l0.80205,-6.45h8.30186c3.21571,0 5.97181,-2.40771 6.39541,-5.59756l3.15361,-23.65c0.51087,-3.82834 -2.52814,-7.30244 -6.39121,-7.30244h-6.89092zM125.87998,73.1h7.42422c1.33993,0 2.30613,1.10399 2.12901,2.43135l-3.15361,23.65c0,0.0014 0,0.0028 0,0.0042c-0.144,1.08425 -1.04031,1.86445 -2.1332,1.86445h-7.76436l0.82725,-6.65576zM71.02978,81.22129l-1.72168,0.86504l-0.34014,1.89385l1.31855,1.41094l0.74326,0.13018l1.72588,-0.86084l0.33594,-1.89805l-1.31436,-1.40674zM67.87197,88.7001l-1.72168,0.86084l-0.34014,1.89805l1.31855,1.40674l0.74326,0.13437l1.72168,-0.86504l0.34014,-1.89805l-1.31436,-1.40674zM63.33262,95.44404l-1.72168,0.86504l-0.34014,1.89385l1.31855,1.41094l0.74326,0.13018l1.72588,-0.86084l0.33594,-1.89805l-1.31436,-1.40674zM58.12559,135.45l-1.72168,0.86504l-0.34014,1.89385l1.31436,1.40674l0.74746,0.13438l1.72168,-0.86504l0.34014,-1.89385l-1.31436,-1.40674zM66.72559,135.45l-1.72168,0.86504l-0.34014,1.89385l1.31436,1.40674l0.74746,0.13438l1.72168,-0.86504l0.34014,-1.89385l-1.31436,-1.40674zM75.32559,135.45l-1.72168,0.86504l-0.34014,1.89385l1.31436,1.40674l0.74746,0.13438l1.72168,-0.86504l0.34014,-1.89385l-1.31436,-1.40674zM83.92559,135.45l-1.72168,0.86504l-0.34014,1.89385l1.31436,1.40674l0.74746,0.13438l1.72168,-0.86504l0.34014,-1.89385l-1.31436,-1.40674z">
                </path>
              </g>
            </g>
          </svg>
          <br>
          <p>BRANDING</p>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Or using `[aria-selected="true"]` which is used in `a` tag

```css
ul li a:hover svg g,
ul li a[aria-selected="true"] svg g{
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav mb-3 justify-content-around" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="web-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#web" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true" style="text-align: center;">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 172 172" style=" fill:#000000;">
        <g fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal">
          <path d="M0,172v-172h172v172z" fill="none"></path>
          <g fill="#ffffff">
            <path d="M23.65,23.65c-4.72427,0 -8.6,3.87573 -8.6,8.6v116.1h2.15h139.75v-116.1c0,-4.72427 -3.87573,-8.6 -8.6,-8.6zM23.65,27.95h124.7c2.40083,0 4.3,1.89917 4.3,4.3v15.05v96.75h-133.3v-96.75v-15.05c0,-2.40083 1.89917,-4.3 4.3,-4.3zM19.35,47.3c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15zM152.65,47.3c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15zM27.95,32.25c-2.37482,0 -4.3,1.92518 -4.3,4.3c0,2.37482 1.92518,4.3 4.3,4.3c2.37482,0 4.3,-1.92518 4.3,-4.3c0,-2.37482 -1.92518,-4.3 -4.3,-4.3zM40.85,32.25c-2.37482,0 -4.3,1.92518 -4.3,4.3c0,2.37482 1.92518,4.3 4.3,4.3c2.37482,0 4.3,-1.92518 4.3,-4.3c0,-2.37482 -1.92518,-4.3 -4.3,-4.3zM53.75,32.25c-2.37482,0 -4.3,1.92518 -4.3,4.3c0,2.37482 1.92518,4.3 4.3,4.3c2.37482,0 4.3,-1.92518 4.3,-4.3c0,-2.37482 -1.92518,-4.3 -4.3,-4.3zM30.1,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM38.7,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM47.3,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM55.9,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM64.5,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM73.1,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM81.7,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM90.3,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM98.9,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM107.5,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM116.1,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM124.7,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM133.3,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM141.9,45.15c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM36.55,60.2c-3.53669,0 -6.45,2.91331 -6.45,6.45v60.2c0,3.53669 2.91331,6.45 6.45,6.45h2.15c0.77537,0.01097 1.49657,-0.39641 1.88746,-1.06613c0.39088,-0.66972 0.39088,-1.49803 0,-2.16775c-0.39088,-0.66972 -1.11209,-1.07709 -1.88746,-1.06613h-2.15c-1.21481,0 -2.15,-0.93519 -2.15,-2.15v-60.2c0,-1.21481 0.93519,-2.15 2.15,-2.15h38.7c1.21481,0 2.15,0.93519 2.15,2.15v60.2c0,1.21481 -0.93519,2.15 -2.15,2.15h-2.15c-0.77537,-0.01097 -1.49657,0.39641 -1.88746,1.06613c-0.39088,0.66972 -0.39088,1.49803 0,2.16775c0.39088,0.66972 1.11209,1.07709 1.88746,1.06613h2.15c3.53669,0 6.45,-2.91331 6.45,-6.45v-60.2c0,-3.53669 -2.91331,-6.45 -6.45,-6.45zM96.75,60.2c-3.53669,0 -6.45,2.91331 -6.45,6.45v6.45c0,3.53669 2.91331,6.45 6.45,6.45h38.7c3.53669,0 6.45,-2.91331 6.45,-6.45v-6.45c0,-3.53669 -2.91331,-6.45 -6.45,-6.45zM96.75,64.5h38.7c1.21481,0 2.15,0.93519 2.15,2.15v6.45c0,1.21481 -0.93519,2.15 -2.15,2.15h-38.7c-1.21481,0 -2.15,-0.93519 -2.15,-2.15v-6.45c0,-1.21481 0.93519,-2.15 2.15,-2.15zM90.3,90.3v4.3h51.6v-4.3zM90.3,103.2v4.3h51.6v-4.3zM90.3,116.1v4.3h51.6v-4.3zM47.3,129c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM55.9,129c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM64.5,129c-1.18741,0 -2.15,0.96259 -2.15,2.15c0,1.18741 0.96259,2.15 2.15,2.15c1.18741,0 2.15,-0.96259 2.15,-2.15c0,-1.18741 -0.96259,-2.15 -2.15,-2.15zM90.3,129v4.3h30.1v-4.3z">
            </path>
          </g>
        </g>
      </svg>
      <p>WEB DEVELOPMENT</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link" id="graphics-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#graphics" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false" style="text-align: center;">
      <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 172 172"
        style=" fill:#000000;">
        <g fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal">
          <path d="M0,172v-172h172v172z" fill="none"></path>
          <g fill="#ffffff">
            <path d="M13.76,27.52v116.96h82.56c3.29219,0 3.44,-3.44 3.44,-3.44c0,-5.68406 4.63594,-10.32 10.32,-10.32c-5.68406,0 -10.32,-4.63594 -10.32,-10.32c0,-5.68406 4.63594,-10.32 10.32,-10.32h26.51219c1.34375,-1.34375 1.34375,-3.52062 0,-4.86437l-17.2,-18.20781c-1.34375,-1.34375 -3.52062,-1.34375 -4.86437,0l-14.66031,14.66031v-0.01344l-12.85969,12.87313c-0.67188,0.65844 -1.55875,0.99437 -2.44563,0.99437c-0.87344,0 -1.76031,-0.33594 -2.43219,-0.99437c-1.34375,-1.35719 -1.34375,-3.52063 0,-4.87781l13.07469,-13.06125l-30.75844,-33.55344c-0.61812,-0.67188 -1.46469,-1.075 -2.37844,-1.11531c-0.9675,-0.04031 -1.81406,0.29563 -2.48594,0.91375l-38.94188,35.97219v-64.40594h130.72v58.48c-0.01344,1.23625 0.63156,2.39188 1.70656,3.02344c1.075,0.61813 2.39187,0.61813 3.46687,0c1.075,-0.63156 1.72,-1.78719 1.70656,-3.02344v-65.36zM120.4,51.6c-5.6975,0 -10.32,4.6225 -10.32,10.32c0,5.6975 4.6225,10.32 10.32,10.32c5.6975,0 10.32,-4.6225 10.32,-10.32c0,-5.6975 -4.6225,-10.32 -10.32,-10.32zM151.36,113.52c-2.45906,0 -4.71656,1.31688 -5.95281,3.44h-35.32719c-1.23625,-0.01344 -2.39187,0.63156 -3.02344,1.70656c-0.61813,1.075 -0.61813,2.39187 0,3.46687c0.63156,1.075 1.78719,1.72 3.02344,1.70656h35.32719c1.22281,2.12313 3.49375,3.44 5.95281,3.44c2.45906,0 4.71656,-1.31687 5.95281,-3.44h11.24719c1.23625,0.01344 2.39188,-0.63156 3.02344,-1.70656c0.61813,-1.075 0.61813,-2.39187 0,-3.46687c-0.63156,-1.075 -1.78719,-1.72 -3.02344,-1.70656h-11.24719c-1.22281,-2.12312 -3.49375,-3.44 -5.95281,-3.44zM130.72,134.16c-2.45906,0 -4.71656,1.31688 -5.95281,3.44h-14.68719c-1.23625,-0.01344 -2.39187,0.63156 -3.02344,1.70656c-0.61813,1.075 -0.61813,2.39187 0,3.46687c0.63156,1.075 1.78719,1.72 3.02344,1.70656h14.68719c1.22281,2.12313 3.49375,3.44 5.95281,3.44c2.45906,0 4.71656,-1.31687 5.95281,-3.44h31.88719c1.23625,0.01344 2.39188,-0.63156 3.02344,-1.70656c0.61813,-1.075 0.61813,-2.39187 0,-3.46687c-0.63156,-1.075 -1.78719,-1.72 -3.02344,-1.70656h-31.88719c-1.22281,-2.12312 -3.49375,-3.44 -5.95281,-3.44zM151.36,154.8c-2.45906,0 -4.71656,1.31688 -5.95281,3.44h-35.32719c-1.23625,-0.01344 -2.39187,0.63156 -3.02344,1.70656c-0.61813,1.075 -0.61813,2.39187 0,3.46687c0.63156,1.075 1.78719,1.72 3.02344,1.70656h35.32719c1.22281,2.12313 3.49375,3.44 5.95281,3.44c2.45906,0 4.71656,-1.31687 5.95281,-3.44h11.24719c1.23625,0.01344 2.39188,-0.63156 3.02344,-1.70656c0.61813,-1.075 0.61813,-2.39187 0,-3.46687c-0.63156,-1.075 -1.78719,-1.72 -3.02344,-1.70656h-11.24719c-1.22281,-2.12312 -3.49375,-3.44 -5.95281,-3.44z">
            </path>
          </g>
        </g>
      </svg>
      <p>GRAPHICS DESIGN</p>
    </a>
  </li>  
</ul>
```